# Find shared IDs with specific pattern

Tags: python

I have a tab-delimited file with 100k lines:**(EDITED)**

```
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
PROT1A1 PROT1B2  
PROT1A5 PROT1B6   
PROT2A1 PROT2B2   
PROT1A2 PROT3B2
PROT3B2 PROT1A2
```

I want to get ID's that match in both directions and have 1A-1B, 1B-1A, save in one file, the rest in another,so:

```
out.txt) PROT1B2 PROT1A1     rest.txt) PROT1A5  PROT1B6 
         PROT1A1 PROT1B2               PROT2A1  PROT2B2
                                       PROT1A2 PROT3B2
                                       PROT3B2 PROT1A2
```

My script gives me bidirectional IDs, but I don't know to to find for specific pattern, with re? I appreciate if you comment on your script, so I can understand and modify it..

```
fileA = open("input.txt",'r')
fileB = open("input_copy.txt",'r')
output = open("out.txt",'w')
out2=open("rest.txt",'w')
dictA = dict()
for line1 in fileA:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    dictA[query] = subject
dictB = dict()
for line1 in fileB:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    dictB[query] = subject
SharedPairs ={}
NotSharedPairs ={}
for id1 in dictA.keys():
    value1=dictA[id1]
    if value1 in dictB.keys():
        if id1 == dictB[value1]: # may be re should go here?
            SharedPairs[value1] = id1
        else:
            NotSharedPairs[value1] = id1
for key in SharedPairs.keys():
    line = key +'\t' + SharedPairs[key]+'\n'
    output.write(line)
for key in NotSharedPairs.keys():
    line = key +'\t' + NotSharedPairs[key]+'\n'
    out2.write(line)
```

Comment: Interesting - although some terminology from non-pythonic domain distracts me - 1A-1B meaning "PROT1A1 PROT1B2" ? Well more python / algo question: Why do you read in the file two times? Was the plan to have to somehow two mappings one first: second, and one "somehow reverse" second: first (only forgot to interchange "query" and "subject" on one of the reading loops)?

Comment: simply, because I did not know how to make it with 1 file..

Comment: Maybe I was unclear - English is not my native language - the code above should map the content of two identical files into identical dicts (as is) and not knowing exactly what is the planned algorithm, I think there is no need for the duplicates ...

Comment: Mmm... I still don't understand what you need, to be more clear, just give an example of input and output of what you expect

Comment: edited for bluesummers. for Dilettant: at this step I exactly need it to print the duplicates,as later i go to create the links...

Comment: So you do not want the filter already upon input, otherwise the "PROT3B2" lines would not even show up in rest.txt, OK (maybe state that in the question, as with big files one usually tries to reduce volume fast, and not knowing the exact what has to be preserved things, ... thanks, will adapt the answer.

Comment: basically rest contains everything else..sorry so confusing

Comment: Answer updated, please check, should suit your needs now (and answer the question as it now stands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the final specification in question here comes the answer suggestion:

```
a_file_name = "input.txt"
a_dict, b_dict = {}, {}
with open(a_file_name, "rt") as i_f:  # read file in context secured block
    for line in i_f:
        line = line.rstrip()  # no trailing white space (includes \n et al.)
        if line:
            pair = [a.strip() for a in line.split('\t')]  # fragile split
            a_dict[pair[0]] = pair[1]
            b_dict[pair[1]] = pair[0]

must_match = sorted(('1A', '1B'))  # Accept only unordered 1A-1B pairs
fix_pos_slice = slice(4, 6)  # Sample: 'PROT1A1' has '1A' on slice(4, 6)

shared, rest = {}, {}
for key_a, val_a in a_dict.items():
    # Below we prepare a canidate for matching against the unordered pair
    fix_pos_match_cand = sorted(x[fix_pos_slice] for x in (key_a, val_a))
    if must_match == fix_pos_match_cand and b_dict.get(key_a) == val_a:
        shared[val_a] = key_a
    else:
        rest[val_a] = key_a

# Output shared and rest into corresponding files
for f_name, data in (("out.txt", shared), ("rest.txt", rest)):
    with open(f_name, 'wt') as o_f:  # Again secured in context block
        for key, val in data.items():
            o_f.write(key + '\t' + val + '\n')
```

Operating on the given (new) `input.txt` (expecting tabs between the words in a line!):

```
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
PROT1A1 PROT1B2  
PROT1A5 PROT1B6   
PROT2A1 PROT2B2   
PROT1A2 PROT3B2
PROT3B2 PROT1A2
```

yields in `out.txt`:

```
PROT1A1 PROT1B2
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
```

and in `rest.txt`:

```
PROT1B6 PROT1A5
PROT2B2 PROT2A1
PROT3B2 PROT1A2
PROT1A2 PROT3B2
```

Comments have been added to highlight some code portions.

## Upon special request here a sketch how to extend to more pairs to match:

To use the same input file (but demonstrate different result) add a hypothetical 1A-3B pair (the 2A-2B is not present in input) to the allowed matches goes like this (one solution):

```
a_file_name = "input.txt"
a_dict, b_dict = {}, {}
with open(a_file_name, "rt") as i_f:  # read file in context secured block
    for line in i_f:
        line = line.rstrip()  # no trailing white space (includes \n et al.)
        if line:
            pair = [a.strip() for a in line.split('\t')]  # fragile split
            a_dict[pair[0]] = pair[1]
            b_dict[pair[1]] = pair[0]

must_match_once = sorted(  # Accept only unordered 1A-1B or 1A-3B pairs
    (sorted(pair) for pair in (('1A', '1B'), ('1A', '3B'))))
fix_pos_slice = slice(4, 6)  # Sample: 'PROT1A1' has '1A' on slice(4, 6)

shared, rest = {}, {}
for key_a, val_a in a_dict.items():
    # Below we prepare a canidate for matching against the unordered pair
    fix_pos_match_cand = sorted(x[fix_pos_slice] for x in (key_a, val_a))
    has_match = any(
        [must_match == fix_pos_match_cand for must_match in must_match_once])
    if has_match and b_dict.get(key_a) == val_a:
        shared[val_a] = key_a
    else:
        rest[val_a] = key_a

# Output shared and rest into corresponding files
for f_name, data in (("out.txt", shared), ("rest.txt", rest)):
    with open(f_name, 'wt') as o_f:  # Again secured in context block
        for key, val in data.items():
            o_f.write(key + '\t' + val + '\n')
```

Operating on the given (identical) `input.txt` (note still expecting tabs between the words in a line!):

```
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
PROT1A1 PROT1B2  
PROT1A5 PROT1B6   
PROT2A1 PROT2B2   
PROT1A2 PROT3B2
PROT3B2 PROT1A2
```

yields in `out.txt`:

```
PROT1A1 PROT1B2
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
PROT3B2 PROT1A2
PROT1A2 PROT3B2
```

and in `rest.txt`:

```
PROT1B6 PROT1A5
PROT2B2 PROT2A1
```

## Upon very, special request here a sketch how to also not shadow partial duplicate pairs:

As usual, real life brings in "duplicates", so upon special request by the OP,
here one final variant, dealing with duplicate first or second column tokens.

One could have also just stored the full pair as string in a set, but keeping the dict on input (with the nice setdefault method and targeting a list of values) is a more adequate approach IMO.

In below variant two other things are changed from the others:

1. The output is collected as pairs (in tuples) appended to lists
2. The output now has source column ordering (the other variants did it the other way around)

Sample (partially) duplicate data dealt with:

```
PROT1A1 PROT1B1
PROT1A1 PROT2B1
```

Source code:

```
a_file_name = "input.txt"
a_dict, b_dict = {}, {}
with open(a_file_name, "rt") as i_f:  # read file in context secured block
    for line in i_f:
        line = line.rstrip()  # no trailing white space (includes \n et al.)
        if line:
            pair = [a.strip() for a in line.split('\t')]  # fragile split
            # Build a dict with list as values
            # ... to keep same key, different value pairs
            a_dict.setdefault(pair[0], []).append(pair[1])
            b_dict.setdefault(pair[1], []).append(pair[0])

must_match_once = sorted(  # Accept only unordered 1A-1B or 2A-2B pairs
    (sorted(pair) for pair in (('1A', '1B'), ('1A', '3B'))))
fix_pos_slice = slice(4, 6)  # Sample: 'PROT1A1' has '1A' on slice(4, 6)

shared, rest = [], []  # Store respective output in lists of pairs (tuples)
for key_a, seq_val_a in a_dict.items():
    for val_a in seq_val_a:
        # Below we prepare a canidate for matching against the unordered pair
        fix_pos_mc = sorted(x[fix_pos_slice] for x in (key_a, val_a))
        has_match = any(
            [must_match == fix_pos_mc for must_match in must_match_once])
        if has_match and b_dict.get(key_a) and val_a in b_dict.get(key_a):
            # Preserve first, second source order by appending in that order
            shared.append((key_a, val_a))
        else:
            rest.append((key_a, val_a))

# Output shared and rest into corresponding files
for f_name, data in (("out.txt", shared), ("rest.txt", rest)):
    with open(f_name, 'wt') as o_f:  # Again secured in context block
        for pair in data:
            o_f.write('\t'.join(pair) + '\n')
```

Operating on the given (degenerated) `input.txt` (note still expecting tabs between the words in a line!):

```
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
PROT1A1 PROT1B2  
PROT1A1 PROT2B2  
PROT1A5 PROT1B6   
PROT2A1 PROT2B2   
PROT1A2 PROT3B2
PROT3B2 PROT1A2
```

yields in `out.txt`:

```
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
PROT1A1 PROT1B2
PROT1A2 PROT3B2
PROT3B2 PROT1A2
```

and in `rest.txt`:

```
PROT1A1 PROT2B2
PROT1A5 PROT1B6
PROT2A1 PROT2B2
```

Thus the "duplicate": `PROT1A1 PROT2B2` is preserved and does not shadow the seeked `PROT1A1 PROT1B2`.

**Previous update**:

Now with better specified task from comment (maybe update the question also):

```
a_file_name = "input.txt"
a_dict, b_dict = {}, {}
fix_pos_match_query = sorted(('1A', '1B'))
fix_pos_slice = slice(4, 6)  # sample 'PROT1A1' has '1A' on slice(4, 6)
with open(a_file_name, "rt") as i_f:
    for line in i_f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line:
            pair = [a.strip() for a in line.split('\t')]
            fix_pos_match_cand = sorted(x[fix_pos_slice] for x in pair)
            if fix_pos_match_query == fix_pos_match_cand:
                a_dict[pair[0]] = pair[1]
                b_dict[pair[1]] = pair[0]

shared, rest = {}, {}
for key_a, val_a in a_dict.items():
    if b_dict.get(key_a) == val_a:
        shared[val_a] = key_a
    else:
        rest[val_a] = key_a

for f_name, data in (("out.txt", shared), ("rest.txt", rest)):
    with open(f_name, 'wt') as o_f:
        for key, val in data.items():
            o_f.write(key + '\t' + val + '\n')
```

Operating on the given `input.txt`:

```
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
PROT1A1 PROT1B2 
PROT1A5 PROT1B6  
PROT2A1 PROT2B2
```

yields in `out.txt`:

```
PROT1A1 PROT1B2
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
```

and in `rest.txt`:

```
PROT1B6 PROT1A5
```

This works by expecting the given 2 characters on the exact positions as understood from the samples and the comment.

If this is a protein domain specific task with further variations (e.g. match not on fixed position) a regex would be for sure better, but the question does not provide such a variability. In case it is needed, simply replace the filter upon input line with one working on the match (or not match) of a regex.

**Old**:

First answer with simple full match filter:

A trial for an answer - or at least some hints on how to write the code more pep8 like readable for others - and with a simple filter based on the requested existence of a specific pair upon input:

```
a_file_name = "input.txt"
a_dict, b_dict = {}, {}
filter_on_read = sorted(('PROT1B2', 'PROT1A1'))
with open(a_file_name, "rt") as i_f:
    for line in i_f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line:
            pair = [a.strip() for a in line.split('\t')]
            if filter_on_read == sorted(pair):
                a_dict[pair[0]] = pair[1]
                b_dict[pair[1]] = pair[0]

shared, rest = {}, {}
for key_a, val_a in a_dict.items():
    if b_dict.get(key_a) == val_a:
        shared[val_a] = key_a
    else:
        rest[val_a] = key_a

for f_name, data in (("out.txt", shared), ("rest.txt", rest)):
    with open(f_name, 'wt') as o_f:
        for key, val in data.items():
            o_f.write(key + '\t' + val + '\n')
```

on my machine given:

```
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
PROT1A1 PROT1B2 
PROT1A5 PROT1B6  
PROT2A1 PROT2B2
```

yields in `out.txt`:

```
PROT1A1 PROT1B2
PROT1B2 PROT1A1
```

and in `rest.txt`nothing (for this input) as the rest was filtered out upon read already.

Please note: There will be more elegant versions esp. when reading huge files ... and we might miss data, as we only - like the questions code - loop over one side of the mapping a map from first to second entry, if there are duplicate first entries but with differing second entries the last will override the data from the previous read, and the former will never been output.

So there may be entries in `b_dict` that you will never see in the output files.

HTH python is a wonderful language ;-)

Comment: it looks good, but that doesn't  look for a specific pattern, like if i have PROT1A2 PROT3B2 and PROT3B2 PROT1A2, I dont want it to be in my out.txt file..you know what I mean..?Should i edit my example above?

Comment: That should be easy, if only the task would be clear: What is such a "pattern"? Would a grep on the input file already optimally prepare the task by only allowing the ingredients? Say `grep -e "PROT1A1" -e "PROT1B2" input_raw.txt > input.txt` and then run the python script should go a long way ;-)

Comment: No, I could do it separately in many ways using re as well, but I need to automate the code by first taking all ID's that math in bidirectional way and has 1A-1B in ID's..

Comment: Please check the updated answer; Are you asking for regex solution, because when you state "1A-1B" you mean any text with either a 1 directly followed by either an A or a B (or only in some positions ...) - sorry but these text codes do not mean anything to me, maybe it is well known to others.

Comment: and if I have 50000 1A's and 1B's? (( any text with either a 1 directly followed by either an A or a B, bcos my protein names are different only 1A, 1B, is always there.. (it is chromosomes)

Comment: @user3224522 Please recheck the update. Maybe also update the question, as knowledge on proteins or the specific occurrences may not be clear for a simply python tagged question.

Comment: super. last Q: If I want 1A-1B and 2A-2B how to add them in the must match? thanks!

Comment: there is smth wrong in the code...as it doesnt give me shared pairs when I run it on my big file....

Comment: Oh,... instead it gives? The splits are fragile, otherwise lots of things can go wrong, pnly you can look after as we do not have access to your machines hopefully ;-)

Comment: it gives me shared, but also some not shared pairs...((

Comment: ... is there a non-shared pair ending up in shared one could try as a minimal sample where above code goes wrong? Are these wrong ones, matched by the filter pattern, or not?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you think it might be because I have duplicate first entries with differing second entries?

Comment: As noted in the answer: In case of identical first entries but differing second ones you need a different strategy, as the split and use of first as key hides all former occurrences (per ordering on input). One way would be to key the full pair and make the split in the detection / switching loop processing, another would be having lists as values in the dicts, giving you the capacity to keep those occurrences, and also adapt then the processing by looping over the values per key ... I can provide a sample, but we need to watch out for endless evolving question ;-) but if you ask, I provide.

Comment: yes, could you pls, I can ask as a new question...?

Comment: Maybe better I edit/extend the answer - as we already have far too many questions on elementary python usage here. Maybe more use case centric would be a good addition - may take a while though, this is best effort community support :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135031/discussion-between-user3224522-and-dilettant).